# How to correctly upload a file to a directory

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to my directory located on a server through `inputfile` HTML and I manipulate it from the server with PHP where I indicate the path in which I want it to be saved, but I cannot save the file when I give it in the action On uploading file I get the following error:

> Warning : move_uploaded_file(//TestServer/Folder/File_00001.pdf):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\project\server.php on line 96
>
> Warning : move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
> 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpBCE0.tmp' to '//TestServer/Folder/File_00001.pdf' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\project\server.php on line

The PHP code that I use to load the document is as follows:

```
$filePDF= $_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["name"];
        $pathPDF= "//TestServer/Folder/";
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $pathPDF. $filePDF)){
           echo"File Upload Success";
        }else{
            echo"Error Upload Fie";
        }
```

I do not know if there is something that I am missing in the sentence that I have just shared or if I know what I am doing wrong

Comment: @LawrenceCherone — That's a completely different location though! It's probably not even on the same computer as the OP's desired target.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone — It would probably be more useful to explain how to translate that network path syntax into something PHP can understand then to suggest code that will save the file in a completely different place (while implying that it will give them what they want).